# How to display two objects on one JFrame while keeping their positions?

Tags: java

Basically, I have one class where I've drawn a flower, and positioned it on the left of the screen
and another where I've drawn a sun in the top right.
How would I exactly draw the two together? In any way? All this JFrame and Component stuff is confusing me, can someone explain it?
Overall, i want users to be able to answer questions to decide which flower to draw. I really don't know how to do that either.
Can someone get me on the right track?

Comment: The answer would depend on how you've established the other two classes. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I legitimately have no idea what I'm doing. I literally just made one class that draws a sun and another that draws a flower and I have no idea where to go from there

Answer (score 1):

I think that the basic solution you want is to create two sub-components to sit side by side in your main frame/pane. To control where each component, be it a picture, some text, a button, etc.. sits you should use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I am not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve so I suggest you look through the options and choose which works best for you. Personally I think the gridLayout will do you justice. There are some good examples in the above link too.